# Add border at the end of bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I add an a border at the end of the bootstrap 4 table? Similar like it has added a border on the top.

Bootstrap table: https://jsfiddle.net/mkdeveloper2021/Lrf4gemq/1/

Code:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the [`border-bottom`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/) class to your table: `<table class="table border-bottom">`

**[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q80kx4zw/1/)**